# Cómo rescatar multiples valores desde un JSP hacia el controlador en java

Tags: java, html, mvc, spring, jsp

Desde el JSP necesito rescatar múltiples valores mediante un "select multiple", dentro de ese select tiene una lista de usuarios de la cual si se van seleccionando, van quedando marcados, y son esos usuarios marcados los que debo rescatar hacia el controlador, he aquí un poco de código.

```html
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple"  name="userTxt" multiple="multiple" id="TipoUsuario">
        <c:forEach items="${listadoUs1}" var="lista" varStatus="loop">
          <option value="${lista.getId()}"  >${lista.nombre}</option>       
        </c:forEach> 
        <c:forEach items="${listadoUser2}" var="lista" varStatus="loop">
           <option value="${lista.getId()}"   ${lista.getEmail() == user.getUsuario() ? 'selected="selected"' : ''}   >${lista.getNombre()}     </option>       
        </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Como se puede apreciar, tengo 2 foreach, puesto que vienen de diferentes tablas, cada usuario que voy seleccionando va quedando marcado, y es eso lo que debo rescatar en el controlador para manipular sus datos.

Sé que la manera de rescatar datos es la siguiente

```java
String prov = request.getParameter("userTxt");
```

Pero me extrae 1 solo.

La otra manera es insertarlo dentro de un `array[]` pero no logro hacerlo bien.

```java
String[] indice = request.getParameter("userTxt").split("-");
```

Espero puedan ayudar y aconsejarme respecto a esto. Muchas gracias!!!